# How to implements Role based Authentication and Access Control in Laravel

Tags: laravel, acl

I want to create Role based login with access permission using laravel. I want to develop it without any third-party library. How can i develop it best and effective way.

Comment: There is no a best way. There are plenty of ways to implement that and it totally depends on your needs.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Authorization documentation`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) and gates.

Comment: can you suggests to me some resource,where it's beautifully implemented.

Comment: what you tried before ?

Comment: This is good [package, laravel permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: You can use this library https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation for access control for admin and Agent Roles (Adapt this to fit your use case).

I have a boolean field in my user table(`is_admin`) which is `0` for agents and 1 for admins. so in my `User model` I did this

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_admin' => 'boolean',
];

public function isAdmin()
{
        return $this->is_admin;
}
```

Create a new `middleware` for the type of roles u want using

```
$php artisan make:middleware Admin

$php artisan make:middleware Agent
```

The middleware files will be created in App\Http\Middleware\ add this to class inside Admin.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() ){

        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/agent');

}
```

and this to Agent.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isAdmin()){

        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/admin');

}
```

After this register your middleware with laravel. 
To do this add this to `$routeMiddleware` in your `Kernel.php` which is located at `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
'agent' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Agent',
```

Make sure to create proper routes for redirection as we've mentioned in our middleware files. 
After this you are almost done.

Now to verify if a user is admin or normal user add this to the constructor method of your `controller`.

Actions allowed only for admins,

```
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }
```

Action allowed only for agents,

```
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->middleware('agent');
    }
```

That's it now you have a Admin and Agent role in your app and you can control access for each of them by using their respective middlewares!